# Is there a way to set environment variables in a google cloud (GCP) VM instance in the .bashrc file like how I do with my other VMs?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, cron, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

I'm doing work in the [GCP](https://www.google.com/search?q=GCP&oq=GCP&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i60.513j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and specifically in their [VMs](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) product. I am working on Ubuntu 18.04. I have a .bashrc file with a lot of exports to create environment variables, similar to my environment I run locally.

```
export ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXX"
export BASE_URL="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"
export TWILLIO_ACCOUNT_SID=XXXXXXXX
```

And this works fine in my terminal on my mac, and the command `printenv` prints these all out. However, when I run jobs that use the environment variables from crontab, I get errors that say they are missing the environment variable.

I run the job not from crontab and it seems to work fine, and the way I run them in crontab is identical to the way I run them from the terminal.

crontab definition

```
*/15 * * * * python3 /path/to/file/check_eth_balance.py >> /path/to/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

How I run from terminal:

```
python3 /path/to/file/check_eth_balance.py >> /path/to/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

I've also run the suggestions from [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

```
*/15 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; python3 /path/to/file/check_eth_balance.py >> /path/to/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

Do I have to [set environment variables the google cloud way](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables) instead of what I've come to think of as the "normal" way?

Comment: Howdy ... your question is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables .... this is a crontab story as opposed to a GCP story.

Comment: Yes apologies, I meant to add that I tried that as well, and they still weren't picking up the environment variables. I'll fix.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321051/gcloud-compute-instances-add-metadata-set-environment-variable/67193838#67193838

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this via instance / project metadata.

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance --tags http-server \
--metadata startup-script='#! /bin/bash
# set env vars
apt-get update
export bar=foo
EOF'
```

see the link for further information: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

You can set project metadata and override it on instance level if you need to do this on a wider scale.

Comment: You should provide the information with your answer, and not provide off-site links.

Comment: This post does not answer the question of how to set `environment` variables. This answer is for `metadata` which is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up John. Fixed it :)