# How can I inject an environment variable into the startup script for gcloud compute instances create?

Tags: environment-variables, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am creating a GCE VM with the `gcloud compute instances create` command and I am using the `--metadata-from-files` argument to pass in a startup shell script for some provisioning.

However, I need for a variety of environment variables to be pre-populated with specified values in order for the startup script to work. They can't be hard-coded into the startup script because they will be different for different users of the overall script I am writing (eg the env vars passed into the new instance might be based on the $USER invoking the script).

I tried adding key value pairs with the `--metadata` argument as well, but this does not work, and the referenced shell variables are still unbound in the execution of the startup script.

How can I issue a gcloud compute instances create command that forwards some set of environment variables that will be populated into the environment for the startup script to consume them?

The `--metadata` parameter seems like it should be correct since the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--metadata) say,

> Metadata to be made available to the guest operating system running on the instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use this documentation to generate the appropriate `curl` commands to extract your metadata:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

You can then use the extracted values to set your environment variables.

(Edited to fix the URL.)

Comment: This helped a lot and I think I have it working. One note you may want to add to your answer is that you'll need the explicit query to the `attributes` endpoint for the metadata. Also I think your link is broken

Comment: I actually realized there is an issue with this type of answer. This requires you to ensure `curl` is provisioned on the instance so that you can retrieve the metadata. But for example, some of the provisioning steps might be to check whether that user has already provisioned the machine (since GCE forces these scripts to run every time the instance is resumed) and skip some provisioning if it was already run (i.e. by checking for a certain file or something). It creates a chicken and egg problem where you essentially have to at minimum reprovision curl no matter what.

Comment: If instead the `instances create` command could actually forward env vars to the instance, it would solve this without needing to rely on network access to the metadata for variables.